# How to simulate realistic TCP traffic in OMNeT++?

Tags: http, simulation, omnet++, traffic-simulation

I want to simulate TCP traffic between a source and destination pair, using OMNeT++, such that:

1. there is a periodic transmission of a 2GB file (every 1.5-2.0 second, as allowed by TCP congestion mechanism)
2. the traffic being simulated must be permitted to grow with the TCP congestion window dominating its bit-rate. The maximum bit-rate must be limited by the link bandwidth
3. as soon as the file is completely transmitted, automatically restart the transmission of next 2GB file
4. calculate average bandwidth consumption on the link

Is there any module or feature which supports this functionality?

I have tried to use NS3 for this scenario but it did not have a method to automatically restart the application once the first transmission is completed.

Thanks for your answers in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the little that i know about Omnet++, the best framework to such real application is the Inet framework, which implements TCP/UDP, IP and other real protocol.

Comment: Yes, that's what I found too. Thanks.